# Iterate over two lists of dicts and create list of tuples without loop

Tags: python

I have two lists of dicts: `list1` and `list2`.

```
print(list1)
[{'name': 'fooa', 'desc': 'bazv', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1},
 {'name': 'bard', 'desc': 'besd', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1},
 {'name': 'baer', 'desc': 'bees', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1},
 {'name': 'aaaa', 'desc': 'bnbb', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2},
 {'name': 'cgcc', 'desc': 'dgdd', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2}]

print(list2)
[{'name': 'foo', 'desc': 'baz', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1},
 {'name': 'bar', 'desc': 'bes', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1},
 {'name': 'bar', 'desc': 'bes', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1},
 {'name': 'aaa', 'desc': 'bbb', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2},
 {'name': 'ccc', 'desc': 'ddd', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2}]
```

I need a list of tuples that will hold two paired dicts (one dict from each list) with the same `city` and `ID`.

I did it with double loop:

```
list_of_tuples = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i['ID'] == j['ID'] and i['city'] == j['city']:
            list_of_tuples.append((i, j))
print(list_of_tuples)

[({'name': 'fooa', 'desc': 'bazv', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1},
  {'name': 'foo', 'desc': 'baz', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1}),
 ({'name': 'fooa', 'desc': 'bazv', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1},
  {'name': 'bar', 'desc': 'bes', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1}),
 ({'name': 'bard', 'desc': 'besd', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1},
  {'name': 'bar', 'desc': 'bes', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1}),
 ({'name': 'baer', 'desc': 'bees', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1},
  {'name': 'bar', 'desc': 'bes', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1}),
 ({'name': 'aaaa', 'desc': 'bnbb', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2},
  {'name': 'aaa', 'desc': 'bbb', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2}),
 ({'name': 'aaaa', 'desc': 'bnbb', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2},
  {'name': 'ccc', 'desc': 'ddd', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2}),
 ({'name': 'cgcc', 'desc': 'dgdd', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2},
  {'name': 'aaa', 'desc': 'bbb', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2}),
 ({'name': 'cgcc', 'desc': 'dgdd', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2},
  {'name': 'ccc', 'desc': 'ddd', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2})]
```

**Question:** How to do this in a more pythonic way (without loops)?

Comment: There is nothing non-pythonic about loops.

Comment: @ScottHunter Correct. But you must agree there are more pythonic ways to do this

Comment: Are you open to using pandas?

Comment: You could write a *list comprehension*, that's more idiomatic (and faster) than  repeatedly appending to a list, but there'll still be a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry I put it wrong. I meant without using loops. Maybe using a list comprehension.

Comment: @lemon you realise that a list comprehension is just different syntax for a loop, right? There's a lot of pushing for 1-liners here but often they become a mess and won't run must faster, if at all

Comment: @roganjosh, Of course, I just want the code to be more laconic

Comment: Did you try just ```list_of_tuples = list(zip(list1, list2))```?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and `filter`:

```
from itertools import product


list1 = [{'name': 'fooa', 'desc': 'bazv', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1},
         {'name': 'bard', 'desc': 'besd', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1},
         {'name': 'baer', 'desc': 'bees', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1},
         {'name': 'aaaa', 'desc': 'bnbb', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2},
         {'name': 'cgcc', 'desc': 'dgdd', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2}]

list2 = [{'name': 'foo', 'desc': 'baz', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1},
         {'name': 'bar', 'desc': 'bes', 'city': 1, 'ID': 1},
         {'name': 'bar', 'desc': 'bes', 'city': 2, 'ID': 1},
         {'name': 'aaa', 'desc': 'bbb', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2},
         {'name': 'ccc', 'desc': 'ddd', 'city': 1, 'ID': 2}]

def condition(x):
    return x[0]['ID'] == x[1]['ID'] and x[0]['city'] == x[1]['city']

list_of_tuples = list(filter(condition, product(list1, list2)))
```

Comment: I retract my earlier statement. You actually managed to make it readable.

Comment: yes I was rushing through I need to get back to my work now

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem well suited for `pandas`. If you convert the lists to DataFrames, matching the records on `ID` and `city` is the same as an [inner join of the two DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

```
import pandas as pd

# convert lists to DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)

# merge the two DataFrames
print(df1.merge(df2, on=["ID", "city"]))
#   ID  city desc_x name_x desc_y name_y
#0   1     1   bazv   fooa    baz    foo
#1   1     1   bazv   fooa    bes    bar
#2   1     2   besd   bard    bes    bar
#3   1     2   bees   baer    bes    bar
#4   2     1   bnbb   aaaa    bbb    aaa
#5   2     1   bnbb   aaaa    ddd    ccc
#6   2     1   dgdd   cgcc    bbb    aaa
#7   2     1   dgdd   cgcc    ddd    ccc
```

Now you have the matched records in each row. Since the `desc` and `name` columns were present in both (and not used for the merge), they get subscripted with `_x` and `_y` to differentiate between the two souce DataFrames.

You just need to reformat it to be in your desired output. You can achieve this using `to_dict` and a list comprehension:

```
list_of_tuples = [
    (
        {"name": r["name_x"], "desc": r["desc_x"], "city": r["city"], "ID": r["ID"]},
        {"name": r["name_y"], "desc": r["desc_y"], "city": r["city"], "ID": r["ID"]}
    ) for r in df1.merge(df2, on=["ID", "city"]).to_dict(orient="records")
]

print(list_of_tuples)
#[({'ID': 1, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'bazv', 'name': 'fooa'},
#  {'ID': 1, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'baz', 'name': 'foo'}),
# ({'ID': 1, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'bazv', 'name': 'fooa'},
#  {'ID': 1, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'bes', 'name': 'bar'}),
# ({'ID': 1, 'city': 2, 'desc': 'besd', 'name': 'bard'},
#  {'ID': 1, 'city': 2, 'desc': 'bes', 'name': 'bar'}),
# ({'ID': 1, 'city': 2, 'desc': 'bees', 'name': 'baer'},
#  {'ID': 1, 'city': 2, 'desc': 'bes', 'name': 'bar'}),
# ({'ID': 2, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'bnbb', 'name': 'aaaa'},
#  {'ID': 2, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'bbb', 'name': 'aaa'}),
# ({'ID': 2, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'bnbb', 'name': 'aaaa'},
#  {'ID': 2, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'ddd', 'name': 'ccc'}),
# ({'ID': 2, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'dgdd', 'name': 'cgcc'},
#  {'ID': 2, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'bbb', 'name': 'aaa'}),
# ({'ID': 2, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'dgdd', 'name': 'cgcc'},
#  {'ID': 2, 'city': 1, 'desc': 'ddd', 'name': 'ccc'})]
```

Comment: "This is a problem well suited for pandas". Unless he's already using pandas for this project, adding pandas as a dependency (and all its transitive dependencies) isn't a good solution for this problem ;-)

Comment: @Guybrush by "this problem" I meant the problem of merging datasets using primary keys

Answer (score 1):

Having nested loops is not "not pythonic". However, you can achieve the same result with a list comprehension. I don't think it's more readable though:

```
[(i, j) for j in list2 for i in list1 if i['ID'] == j['ID'] and i['city'] == j['city']]
```

Comment: Using list comprehension is not always more "pythonic", in this case that just made the nested loops less readable imo.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you @Delgan. In this specific case, I would personally go for the nested loops solution that is more readable.

Comment: What do you mean list comprehensions isn't more pythonic?

Comment: @ritlew First, what does "Pythonic" exactly mean? I think readability and simplicity are better goals that "Pythonicity" :-)